# Making static ReentrantLocks

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrantlock

I've stumbled upon this thread some time ago: [Does making a reentrant lock static and make it a mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678741/does-making-a-reentrant-lock-static-and-make-it-a-mutex/5678791?noredirect=1#comment82392332_5678791) and I have an additional question on my own:

Im interested if creating a `private static final ReentrantLock lock` is not considered a **code smell**? I've read that static variables are evil, yet my current use case Im working on looks like ideal place to use one.

Anyone care to help?

**Edit with details:** I have this class, call it `FileProcessor` which does a given job in another thread. My use case is spinning up a few of these instances of this class and doing those jobs. But what I want to do is to make sure only one of them will make this job at once and they will take turns in performing the work.

So I figured out Ill give them a `static ReentrantLock` that will `lock()` as first thing in `run()` block and `unlock()` as last. This way they have a shared lock that will guard the processing synchronization.

Thanks.

Comment: Saying "static variables are evil" without any context is just useless. Without seeing your use case, it's hard to say whether it's a good idea or not. Generally speaking there's nothing evil in `static`. You can abuse it of course, but you can abuse a lot of things.

Comment: edited and added more details

Comment: No problem in using a static ReentrantLock. It seems to fit your use case well. You can also use `synchronized (this) {}` to achieve the same thing without using an explicit lock. This does not provide as much granularity, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Using a static `Lock` for synchronization at the class level is absolutely normal. You can also use

```
synchronized (FileProcessor.class) {
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, but I think it is worth suggesting that the poster consider using an ExecutorService. Even if you don't use a non-blocking model now, it will be easier to move to one.

Answer (score 0):

For some time, using a global variable was the best option. With the Concurrency API, you have much more simple approaches, for example:

1. You can create a `Runnable` that executes the code in `FileProcessor` and submit it to an `Executor`. You configure the executor to single threaded and you're done.
2. If you have several places where you can start a job and you want to make sure that only one ever runs. Imagine you want to run it right when the program starts and then at 16:00. Now someone starts the program at 15:59 - the job might be started twice. To avoid this, protect the code with an `AtomicBoolean`:

   ```
   private AtomicBoolean guard = new AtomicBoolean(true);

   if (guard.getAndSet(false)) {
       try {
           ... do job ...
       } finally {
           guard.set(true);
       }            
   }
   ```